# Issue with search result

Tags: c#, foreach, active-directory

I'm using C# MVC 5. I've made a connection to active directory and I'm trying to loop through AD to find specifics user through an html form. The results in the POST are not what to be expected. I get the correct AMOUNT(number) of search results, but it is outputting the same result. As shown below:

[image]

2 results in total is correct, however there is also a Josh Barber and not just a Josh VanDyke.
Here is the code:

```
            /**********Establish Connection********/
            DirectoryEntry dir = createDirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);

            /****Refer to class constructor****/
            ADUser userAttributes = new ADUser("", "", "", "", "", "", "");

            /********Create the List to store results in***************/
            List<ADUser> Users = new List<ADUser>();
            string DisplayName = "", SAMAccountName = "", Mail = "", Description = "", Division = "", TelephoneNumber = "", FacsimileTelephoneNumber = "";

            /*******Filter parameters************/
            search.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(anr=" + userName + "* ))";
            SearchResultCollection searchresult = search.FindAll();
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Mail");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Description");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("TelephoneNumber");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("FacsimileTelephoneNumber");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Division");

             /*****************Filtering and populating the List****************/    

            if (searchresult != null)
            {
                foreach (SearchResult iResult in searchresult)
                {
                    foreach (string PropertyName in iResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        foreach (Object key in iResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties[PropertyName])
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                switch (PropertyName.ToUpper())
                                {
                                    case "DISPLAYNAME":
                                        DisplayName = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.Name = DisplayName;
                                        break;

                                    case "SAMACCOUNTNAME":
                                        SAMAccountName = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.DomainUserName = SAMAccountName;
                                        break;

                                    case "MAIL":
                                        Mail = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.EmailAddress = Mail;
                                        break;

                                    case "DESCRIPTION":
                                        Description = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.JobDescription = Description;
                                        break;

                                    case "TELEPHONENUMBER":
                                        TelephoneNumber = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.TelephoneNumber = TelephoneNumber;
                                        break;

                                    case "FACSIMILETELEPHONENUMBER":
                                        FacsimileTelephoneNumber = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.FaxNumber = FacsimileTelephoneNumber;
                                        break;

                                    case "DIVISION":
                                        Division = key.ToString();
                                        userAttributes.Division = Division;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                    }

                    Users.Add(userAttributes);
                }

                return View(Users);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not re-create or clean up `userAttributes`.

```
   // not here
   /****Refer to class constructor****/
   // ADUser userAttributes = new ADUser("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
    ...

         foreach (SearchResult iResult in searchresult)
         {
             // but here.
             ADUser userAttributes = new ADUser("", "", "", "", "", "", "");

             foreach (string PropertyName in iResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
             {
```